# Pyodbc doesn't drop connection once script closes

Tags: python, pyodbc

I use PYODBC to connect to database ( its rare kind of database ) but Pyodbc doesn't drop connection even when I close it explicity

`cnxn.close()`

is there any issue in pyodbc or is there any better way of closing the connection

I tried to use different  methods on database side as well did it on scripting but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the cursor first?

```
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: While that is good form, it is not strictly necessary to close the cursor before closing its connection. After the connection is closed, any attempt to use the cursor results in "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The cursor's connection has been closed."